# Estoy haciendo un programa en c con funciones que me diga si una palabra es un palíndromo o no, todo bien pero al ingresar 8 o mas letras falla,nosepq

Tags: array, c

Es un programa en c a base de funciones y de la función strlen para saber si una palabra es palíndromo o no, cuando ingreso de 1 a 7 letras, funciona correctamente, sin embargo si ingreso 8 o mas el programa me dice siempre que no es palíndromo, no se a que se deba, el código no tiene errores, es un programa que debo corregir y no se si ayude pero la maestra dijo que no era cuestión de agregarle o quitarle alguna instrucción o variable, sino que es algo mínimo y creo que mas sencillo, aunque no logro saber que es :(

```
//PALINDROMO.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X=x;
    dwPos.Y=y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon,dwPos);
}
void Determinar(char palabra1[]);
void Presenta(char *aux);
void main()
{    char Palabra1[80];
      system("cls");
       gotoxy(20,5);printf("Programa que determina si una palabra es palindromo");
       gotoxy(30,6);printf("Nombre:    Grupo:   Fecha:  ");
       gotoxy(30,8);printf("Escribe una palabra: ");
       gets(Palabra1);
       Determinar(Palabra1);
}
void Determinar(char palabra1[])  
{    int L1,I,J,L2;
    char palabra2[80],*Aux;
    L1=strlen(palabra1);
       L2=L1-1;
       for(I=L2,J=0;I>=0,J<=L2;I--,J++)
        palabra2[J]=palabra1[I];
    if(strcmp(palabra1,palabra2)==0)
           Aux="es palindromo";
    else
        Aux="no es palindromo";
    Presenta(Aux);    
}
void Presenta(char *aux)
{    gotoxy(30,10);printf("La palabra %s",aux);
      gotoxy(30,15);printf("Pulsa cualquier tecla para salir");
     getch();    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la función [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) espera que ambas cadenas estén terminadas por un caracter nulo (0).

Por un lado, el arreglo `palabra2` no fue inicializado, así que el resto de sus bytes contienen valores aleatorios, no necesariamente 0.

La forma más simple de inicializarlo es con un literal de caracter:

```
char palabra2[80] = "";
```

Para asegurarte de que la cadena esté terminada en un caracter nulo, luego del último caracter agrega uno:

```
for (I=L2,J=0; I>=0,J<=L2 ;I--,J++)
    palabra2[J] = palabra1[I];

palabra2[J] = 0;
```